# Query with wildcard and mandatory clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012, boolean-logic

I have two tables, TableA and TableB which has to be join in such a way

- ColumnA is mandatory to match
- ColumnB and ColumnC can match (if not then should be considered as wildcard)

I have written below query for this

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA  JOIN TableB ON (TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA) AND
(TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB OR TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC)
```

In words, ColumnA should be matched with ColumnA while if ColumnB (from TableB) is NULL then consider it as a wildcard and if ColumnC (From TableB) is a NULL then consider it as a wild card.

Now, I suspect that this will not generate correct result because as per boolean math

[image]

Which has

> True AND False = False

What I am looking for

```
True AND (True OR False) = True
True AND (True OR True) = True
True AND (False OR True) = True
False AND (True OR True) = False
False AND (True or False) = False
False AND (False OR True) = False
False AND (False OR False) = False
```

{This is just a part of large query so I am not to share the complete example, I'm sorry for that}

Comment: If you don't really care is B or C match, then why not just `TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA`?

Comment: @DavidG as per my requirement; I have to identify matches for ColumnC and ColumnB (if available) and put a flag in 'Match find" column [For colB and C only]. I worst case, I have to skip the "match find column" from the requirement.

Comment: But check the last list of boolean conditions you have, the first boolean matches the `= ...` part, so the logic says `if TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA then TRUE else FALSE`. Columns B and C are just a red herring here.

Comment: @DavidG I think you are correct, I may need to restrict my query to ColumnA only. Let me do some testing on it.

Comment: @DavidG You are correct, SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 AND (0=0 OR 0=0)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  will give 1 anyway. But this will fail at SELECT CASE WHEN 0=0 AND (1=1 OR 1=1)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END which will give 1 instead of 0 (as per my requirement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your logic, columns B and C are really just red herrings here and you can safely ignore them. So your query is much simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA  
JOIN TableB 
    ON TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
```

Additionally, you may want a column to indicate that B or C matched also, so you could do this:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
           WHEN TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB OR TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC 
               THEN 0
               ELSE 1 END 
           AS IsWildcard
FROM TableA  
JOIN TableB 
    ON TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't giving me correct result because there are cases like this ColumnA & Column B should match and ColumnC is wild card. Second case, ColumnA & ColumnC should match and CoulmnB is a wild card. And thrid. ColumnA is matched and columnB and ColumnC are wild card. Any help?